# Signature failed to verify with SHA1withDSA

Tags: java, weblogic, digital-signature, signature

I've written a simple sign code. This simple signature code does not verify.
`dsa.verify(digitalSignature)` returns false. 
Why does this verification fails?
The application server is weblogic 12.2.1.4.0.

```
URL url  = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("sueprv.gsdk");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
byte[] pk = new byte[335];
int rd = (is.read(pk));

privateKey = createPrivateKey(pk);
signature.initSign(privateKey);
byte[] bytes = "this is a test".getBytes();
signature.update(bytes);
byte[] digitalSignature = signature.sign();

URL url1 = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("suepub.gsdk");
InputStream inputStream = url1.openStream();

pk = new byte[444];
rd = (inputStream.read(pk));

Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN");

dsa.initVerify(createPublicKey(pk));

dsa.update(bytes);
System.out.println(dsa.verify(digitalSignature));
```

Answer (score 0):

After so many debugging I found out the trouble from this part of code:

```
rd = (inputStream.read(pk));
```

In code I've read the public key from inputStream with fix size of 444 but in debugging I figured out that 3 bytes of the public key won't read. so this made trouble and because of this the verification of this sign failed.